# Add element outside of Aurelia repeat.for loop based on $index inside of loop

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, repeat, aurelia

I am using Aurelia and Bootstrap grid.  I am looping through some items from the view model, but need to add a clearfix after each 3 items in the grid.  Problem is, I need to add this outside of the loop. HTML:

```
<div class="col-md-4" repeat.for="item of items">
    <div class="inner">
    </div>
</div>
```

I could do something like this...

```
<div if.bind="$index = 2" class="clearfix"></div>
```

But I need it to be outside of the loop.  What's the easiest way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap your `col-md-4` divs with a `template`. Then you can use the `%` (modulus) operator on an inner `template` element to only add the clearfix `div` when needed:

```
<template repeat.for="item of items">
  <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="inner">
      </div>
  </div>
  <template if.bind="$index % 3 === 2">
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
  </template>
</template>
```

Now the `clearfix` will appear at `index` 2, 5 etc

Comment: Why is this the accepted answer? This answer will add unwanted HTML to the DOM when rendered. The solution I provided (and I was the first to answer the question), produces the correct answer without polluting the rendered output with unnecessary HTML elements.

Comment: @AshleyGrant What is being first has got to do with anything? Your `if.bind`, which is the key part of the solution, was totally wrong. I don't dispute the *unwanted HTML* part.

Comment: The `if.bind` part is the easy part of the question, and it was wrong simply because I copied it from the question as the OP had written it. Honestly though, I'm surprised you would have suggested wrapping the HTML with a `div` when my answer that was already posted showed how to do it without adding extra rendered HTML. And having the accepted answer is very important when people google for help. Lots of people just copy/paste the accepted answer, and there's a severe shortcoming with the accepted answer here.

Comment: @AshleyGrant yes, easy for you but OP hadn't considered it and neither did you. So I posted it. I have changed the div to `template` for the future searchers. I will read up on `template`.

Comment: I've edited your answer to be completely correct and not add any unnecessary rendered HTML. I included an inner `template` element so that the second `div` won't be rendered unless necessary.

Comment: The inner `template` element is something I hadn't even though of in my answer yesterday.

Answer (score 2):

Wrap the outer div in a `template` element and then put the `repeat.for` on that `template` element.

```
<template repeat.for="item of items">
  <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="inner">
      </div>
  </div>
  <div if.bind="$index % 3 === 2" class="clearfix"></div>
</template>
```